# Order by most contained in a field from another table

Tags: mysql

Cars table

```
---ID---    ----car----
   1            bmw
   2            mercedes
   3            volvo
```

Posts table

```
---ID---      ----post----
   1              I have a volvo car
   2              I like volvo cars
   3              I dont like bmw
```

I would like to get a result that ordering cars from most contained in posts text to fewer.

Expected result:

```
Volvo
Bmw
Mercedes
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You could try a simple join here with aggregation:

```
SELECT
    c.car
FROM Cars c
LEFT JOIN Posts p
    ON p.post LIKE CONCAT('%', c.car, '%')
GROUP BY
    c.car
ORDER BY
    COUNT(p.ID) DESC;
```

Strictly speaking, we should use a regex match to detect a car name occurring inside a post.  `REGEXP` can be used for that, and the join condition would then become:

```
ON p.post REGEXP CONCAT('[[:<:]]', c.car, '[[:>:]]')
```

Comment: thank you. It does the job well, however with a posts table which has 1500 rows, it took 9 seconds to execute this query, how do you think I can speed this query up?

Comment: If you really need to work directly with the raw text of the posts, then you should look into using full text search.  Otherwise, consider normalizing your data and storing each keyword on a separate row.

Comment: How can I use this query within a fulltext index?

Comment: I tried with LEFT JOIN posts p
   CONTAINS(p.post,c.car) but it does not work?

Answer (score 0):

Try with a correlated subquery at the `ORDER BY` clause:

```
select c.car
from Cars c
order by (
  select count(*) 
  from Posts p
  where concat(' ', p.post, ' ') like concat('% ', c.car, ' %')
) desc
```

I added spaces before and after each column value to avoid false positive results in case a `car` value is contained inside another word in a `post`.
See the [demo](https://www.db-fiddle.com/f/nDqpn1DeKb67bKJKb5xRFJ/2).
Results:

```
| car      |
| -------- |
| volvo    |
| bmw      |
| mercedes |
```

Comment: How can I use MATCH AGAINST in this query?

Comment: I don't think that MATCH AGAINST would work, because: *The search string must be a string value that is constant during query evaluation. This rules out, for example, a table column because that can differ for each row* as is mentioned here: https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.6/en/fulltext-search.html#function_match

Comment: So I cannot use fulltext in this case?

Comment: As far as I know no. Read about match() here: https://database.guide/how-the-match-function-works-in-mysql/

Comment: Thanks. Both 2 answers worked good but I will have to accept the other answer since it is faster than this query and answered earlier.

Comment: @UtkuDalmaz except that the other answer will return false positive results in case the car that you search is contained inside another word in the post.